# Time machine concept in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, timemachine

I am using SonarQube version 5.6 and it is having the feature to "COMPARE". But I am unable to find the **Time Machine** option in this version. In older version like 5.1, Time machine option is available. Is there any way to achieve the same in SonarQube version 5.6 or higher?

Comment: See this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/rpBplmbFFD0)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jeroen Heier for the link. It is very useful and I understood the similar feature of "History" in Measures tab satisfies my requirement. It displays the analysis history in graphical format which is easy to understand.